# Duplicating an Object, Changing a Variable

Tags: php, object

I have the following code:

```
foreach($this->items as $item) {
            
    echobr("a item price: " . $item->price);
    $duplicate = $item;
    $duplicate->price = 0;
    $duplicate->type = "Discount Item";

    echobr("b item price: " . $item->price);
    echobr("c dup item price: " . $duplicate->price);
        // Duplicate new item to cart
        $this->AddItem($duplicate);
}
```

And the output I get is:

```
a item price: 10
b item price: 0
c dup item price: 0
```

So for some reason, changing the price on the temporary variable `$duplicate` changes the price on $this-items, but I dont know why? I thought to do that you'd need the use a reference variable, such as `&$items` ?

Comment: You need to clone the object. That's how it works in many languages, not just PHP.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález How do I clone? And why can't I just make a copy like a normal variable? And so am I right, is duplicate just a pointer or reference variable?

Comment: because the "operator =" create a reference, in other words, the `$duplicate` is just an alias of `$item`

Comment: @Berto99 but why is it that way with objects, and not variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects are [copied by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php). So `$duplicate` points to `$item` in memory. Change one, you change them both.

To get a new object, you must [`clone`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) the original object.

```
$duplicate = clone $item;
```

Comment: Wow, I've never seen that before, in all my years of coding! Thank you so much!

Comment: I asked above, but why is `=` copy by reference with objects, but not with variables?

Comment: Good question. PHP really is just following the lead of other languages here. I am guessing this has to do with better memory usage as objects can be larger in memory than typical scalar variables.

Comment: Wow well thank you.  I've not done a huge amount of OOP programming in PHP, so this was new to me.  Its lovely to learn something new.